# T-SQL Multiple Pivot Column Issue

Tags: sql-server, pivot, multiple-columns

I have a SQL Server table and a query which would result a pivot table with two pivot columns. Previously it worked with only one pivot column (pvt1).

```
SELECT
    MIN([Created Date]),
    MIN([2]) AS [2],
    MIN([4]) AS [4],
    MIN([12]) AS [12],
    MIN([18]) AS [18],
    MIN([47]) AS [47],
    MIN([88]) AS [88],
    MIN([982]) AS [982],
    MIN([1033]) AS [1033],
    MIN([2360]) AS [2360],
    MIN([3759]) AS [3759],
    MIN([3974]) AS [3974],
    MIN([5586]) AS [5586]
FROM 
    (SELECT
         year(udp.CreatedDate) AS "Created Date",
         MAX(udp.Participant) AS "Participant",
         MAX(udp.LastModifiedDate) AS "Last Modified Date",
         MAX(udp.Client) AS "Client"
     FROM
         UDP_Table AS udp
     WHERE
         1=1
     GROUP BY
         year(udp.CreatedDate)) AS source
PIVOT (
    MAX([Last Modified Date])
FOR
  [Participant] IN ([2], [4], [12], [18], [47], [88])
)
as pvt1
PIVOT (
    MAX([Last Modified Date])
FOR
   [Client] IN ([982], [1033], [2360], [3759], [3974], [5586])
)
as pvt2

GROUP BY
    [Created Date]
ORDER BY
    [Created Date] asc
```

And the result is:

> [S0001][207] Invalid column name 'Last Modified Date'.

The weird thing is when I try this example table and query (see the link below) which has the same structure as mine, it works.

http://pratchev.blogspot.de/2009/01/pivoting-on-multiple-columns.html

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

Your first pivot converts the column `[Last Modified Date]` into columns named `[2], [4], [12], [18], [47], [88]` therefore `[Last Modified Date]` doesn't exist for the second pivot.  The example you posted used 2 different columns for each pivot `SUM(value) AS value` and `SUM(quantity) AS quantity`

Im not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish, but based on your final SELECT, you want a column for each Participant and each Client.  You should probably do a UNION to join the records together then do just 1 Pivot.

That would look like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         year(udp.CreatedDate) AS "Created Date",
         MAX(udp.Participant) AS "Participant",
         MAX(udp.LastModifiedDate) AS "Last Modified Date",
     FROM
         UDP_Table AS udp
     GROUP BY
         year(udp.CreatedDate)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
         year(udp.CreatedDate) AS "Created Date",
         MAX(udp.Client) AS "Participant",
         MAX(udp.LastModifiedDate) AS "Last Modified Date",
     FROM
         UDP_Table AS udp
     GROUP BY
         year(udp.CreatedDate)
) AS source
PIVOT (
    MAX([Last Modified Date])
    FOR [Participant] IN ([2], [4], [12], [18], [47], [88], [982], [1033], [2360], [3759], [3974], [5586])
)
as pvt1
```

Comment: So, you say if I used a column for a pivot I cannot use the same column again for a second pivot?